# Java prevent method duplication for same purpose - different parameters

Tags: java, methods, code-duplication

I have 2 methods that are almost identical.  I'd like to know if there is a way to combine these 2 methods into 1, which would allow me to take both types of maps as a parameter.  The methods writes to an excel file.  The key is the excel header (all keys go in first row) and the mapped list are everything beneath each key (the data).  Any unique ideas?

```
private void test(Sheet sheet, HashMap<String, List<Double>> map) {
        for (String var : map.keySet()) {
            int rowNumb=0;
            Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNumb);
            Cell cell = row.createCell(currColumn);
            cell.setCellValue(var);
            rowNumb++;
            List<Double> list = map.get(var);
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                row = sheet.getRow(rowNumb);
                cell = row.createCell(currColumn);
                cell.setCellValue(list.get(i));
            }
            currColumn++;
        }
    }



private void test(Sheet sheet, HashMap<String, List<String>> map) {  <-- takes in String list rather thand Double.
        for (String var : map.keySet()) {
            int rowNumb=0;
            Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNumb);
            Cell cell = row.createCell(currColumn);
            cell.setCellValue(var);
            rowNumb++;
            List<String> list = map.get(var);         <---- Only thing that is different
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                row = sheet.getRow(rowNumb);
                cell = row.createCell(currColumn);
                cell.setCellValue(list.get(i));
            }
            currColumn++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: First idea: Use generics. Questions: what are `currColumn`, `row` and `cell` - where are they defined?

Comment: Ah crap, I took out some things in the first half of the method to make it easier to read.

Comment: Maybe work, maybe not, but you can try this tool: https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.5.2/usage/cpd-usage.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use generics:

```
private <T> void test(Sheet sheet, HashMap<String, List<T>> map) {
    for (String var : map.keySet()) {
        List<T> list = map.get(var);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            row = sheet.getRow(i);
            cell = row.createCell(currColumn);
            cell.setCellValue(list.get(i));
        }
        currColumn++;
    }
}
```

Whereever you previously put any reference to `String` and `Double` now put `T`.

Comment: Thanks.  The issue I'm having with this is the last line:  cell.setCellValue(list.get(i));  setCellValue() doesn't know what to do if it's a type T.  It needs type String or type double, among other things.  This is Apachi package POI for writing to excel if that matters.

Comment: Alright, this works: cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).toString()); .  thanks!